# Aplicar atualizações do código fonte após tempo do fork e várias alterações

Tags: git, github, versionamento

Tenho uma situação em que utilizamos um sistema que o código é open source, porém fizemos algumas modificações para se enquadrar a nossa necessidade.

Agora o sistema original passou por alterações no código para melhorar a segurança, estou olhando os commits deles e implementando as alterações no nosso sistema.

Existe alguma ferramenta, talvez até no próprio git, onde eu pudesse fazer uma comparação, que no caso pegasse o código do dia em que dei o fork no código deles, o meu código atual e o código atual deles e fizesse uma comparação, meio que retornando um código da união das alterações do meu e do deles?

Comment: Desse jeito mágico não, mas o git merge pode ser usado para fazer um merge semi-automático para você entre diferentes branches.

Comment: Você criou de fato um fork do repositório original e começou a subir as alterações para o fork? Ou apenas baixou o código fonte e começou a utilizar no projeto (sem criar seu próprio fork no github)? Só para ter certeza...

Comment: Eu criei um fork do código original, e depois fiz meus próprios commits no meu

Comment: Não acho nada tão mágico, seria uma ferramenta que percorreria e isolaria todas as diferenças dos dois códigos em relação ao original e então indicaria tudo em um único, indicando áreas de conflito e indicando qual é de qual

Comment: Algo que acho que até já vi algo em algum artigo ou reportagem por ai, mas não consigo lembrar de onde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, você tem que garantir que o seu repositório git é uma extensão do projeto original, que ele seja um fork e não apenas uma cópia. Mesmo você copiando, normalmente é para vir uma pasta chamada `.git` que contem as informações necessárias do que chamamos de `origin`.

Sendo assim, você primeiramente necessitará adicionar um remote apontando para o repositório em que foi feito as alterações. Você pode ver como é feito a partir do site do git https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote

`git remote add <name> <url>`

Após isso, você tera um remote para realizar todas as funções do git como `git fetch` `git pull` `git checkout`.

Com isso preparado, você utilizará o `git cherry-pick`. Segundo a documentação:

> Given one or more existing commits, apply the change each one introduces, recording a new commit for each. This requires your working tree to be clean (no modifications from the HEAD commit).

Acessando a documentação você poderá ver exatamente como deve ser usada a ferramente:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Comment: Vou testar amanhã, mas creio que é exatamente isso que preciso